# Symfony 6: Child entities validating incorrectly on user registration form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I got a weired issue which is related to user registration. User has two relationships

```php
<?php
...
Class User {
...
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'owner', targetEntity: Team::class)]
    private Collection $teams;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: Transaction::class)]
    private Collection $transactions;
```

And a simple registration from:

```php
<?php
...
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('full_name', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter full name.',
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter email address.',
                    ]),
                    new Email([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address.',
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'mapped' => false,
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => [
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank([
                            'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                        ]),
                        new Length([
                            'min' => 6,
                            'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                            // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                            'max' => 4096,
                        ]),
                    ]
                ],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Confirm Password'],
            ])
            /* ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ]) */
        ;
    }
...
```

Below is the controller code:

```php
<?php
...
class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
    public function register(
        Request $request,
        UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator,
        AppDefaultAuthenticator $authenticator
    ): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');

            return $userAuthenticator->authenticateUser(
                $user,
                $authenticator,
                $request
            );
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I submit registration form, it shows me two errors that I need to provide user.teams and user.transactions. Below is the screenshot of errors fro _profiler.

[image]

What is this issue and how to solve this?

Comment: how does your User constructor look like? does it have Initialization for the two collections? also, does your getters can handle empty collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections should be initialized and not be null.

in your User Entity you should have something like this:

```
class User
{

   // [...]
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->teams = new ArrayCollection();
       $this->transactions = new ArrayCollection();

   }

   // [....]
}
```

Comment: This, exactly I was missing.  Thank you!